# Execução interrompida

Tags: r, funções, variáveis, dplyr

Estou tentando executar um script, mas está aparecendo o segunte erro:
udunits system database read from C:/Users/André/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/udunits2/share/udunits/udunits2.xml
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'UF'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
Quitting from lines 42-129 (programa.Rmd)
Error: `by` must be supplied when `x` and `y` have no common variables.
i use by = character()` to perform a cross-join.

Backtrace:
x

1. +-rmarkdown::render(...)
2. | -knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
3. |   -knitr:::process_file(text, output)
4. |     +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
5. |     +-knitr:::process_group(group)
6. |     -knitr:::process_group.block(group)
7. |       -knitr:::call_block(x)
8. |         -knitr:::block_exec(params)
9. |           -knitr:::eng_r(options)
10. |             +-knitr:::in_dir(...)
11. |             -knitr:::evaluate(...)
12. |               -evaluate::evaluate(...)
13. |                 -evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
14. |                   +-evaluate:::timing_fn(...)
15. |                   +-base:::handle(...)
16. |                   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
17. |                   +-base::withVisible(eval(expr, envir, enclos))
18. |                   -base::eval(expr, envir, enclos)
19. |                     -base::eval(expr, envir, enclos)
20. +-dplyr::inner_join(codigos, vacina)
21. -dplyr:::inner_join.data.frame(codigos, vacina)
22. -dplyr:::join_mutate(...)
23. ```
    \-dplyr:::join_cols(...)
    ```
24. ```
      \-dplyr:::standardise_join_by(by, x_names = x_names, y_names = y_names)
    ```

Execução interrompida

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Por favor, eu não costumo utilizar este fórum de ajuda. Eu coloquei o erro do modo que aparece no programa. Como eu poderia editar a pergunta? O erro que impede a execução é aquele. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Quais as instruções que deram esse erro? Pode editar a pergunta com o código mínimo capaz de o reproduzir?